# Trouble with Doxygen Function Auto-Link

Tags: doxygen

In my .h file of my C program I have a function:

```
/** Calculates foo using algorithm A1.
 * \param[in] v1 first input
 * \param[in] v2 second input
 * \param[in] s1 first string
 * \param[in] s2 second string
 * \return foo(v1,v2)
 */
int foo( int v1, int v2, char *s1, char *s2);
```

Now in the beginning of the file I want to discuss the function. So I say:

```
/** To facilitate such operations I have:
 *  @li int foo( int v1, int v2, char *s1, char *s2)
 * 
 *  which allows me to blah.
 */
```

Now in my doxygen file, the word *foo* is not linked to the function definition section at the end. However, if I say:

```
/** To facilitate such operations I have:
 *  @li int foo()
 * 
 *  which allows me to blah.
 */
```

The autolinking works fine. Including the arguments breaks the autolinking function and I can't for the life of me figure out why. This happens to all my functions which have > 1 input arguments. `foo()` and `foo(int i)` work but `foo(int i, int j, int k, int m)` does not work. Does anyone have any idea why this occurs?

Comment: What is the definition of your `@li` What happens when you remove the first space in the link request?

Comment: the @li is just a bullet point to include the function in a list. If i remove the bullet point, same thing. I don't understadn why foo() works but foo(args) is bad. I happens to all my functions with <1 input argument too.

Comment: Just to be sure, which version of doxygen. Any special settings in the Doxyfile ?

Comment: Is there a semicolon (`;`) after the definition in your .h file ?

Comment: I'm using Doxygen 1.8.5. As for the doxyfile, I don't think I changed any of the default settings other than specifying file paths to src documents.

Comment: Oh yes. there is a semi-colon. Edited the question to reflects that. Thanks

Comment: OK 1.8.5 is a bit old please update to 1.8.14 (current version) quite a few problems have been solved. Problem is that with version 1.8.5 and the provided code snippets I don't see the problem either. Please extend the description with a complete example that shows the problem.

Comment: I will try my best to update doxygen, though I am on a legacy system and I have to go through my administrator. In the meantime, if anyone has ideas, let me know.

Comment: Best is to extend the example to a, small, full example as with the current information I was not able to reproduce the problem.